# Get phonenumber from addressbook for two textfield

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, addressbook, phone-number

I followed Apple **[Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html)** to get phonenumber from addressbook to my `UITextField`. But I have two `UITextField` and doesn't know how to implement same function to second textfield.

**Presenting the people picker**

```
- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender

{

    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =

            [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;



    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}
```

**Responding to user actions in the people picker**

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:

            (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker

{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}





- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:

            (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker

      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {



    [self displayPerson:person];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];



    return NO;

}



- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:

            (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker

      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person

                                property:(ABPropertyID)property

                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier

{

    return NO;

}
```

**Displaying a person’s information**

```
- (void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person

{

    NSString* name = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,

                                               kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    self.firstName.text = name;



    NSString* phone = nil;

    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person,

                                    kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {

       phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)

               ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);

    } else {

        phone = @"[None]";

    }

    self.phoneNumber.text = phone;

}
```

**EDIT**

```
- (void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person

{

    NSString* phone = nil;

    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {

        phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)

        ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);

    } else {

        phone = @"None";

    }


    self.phoneNumber.text = phone;



    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 1) {

        phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)

        ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 1);

    } else {

        phone = @"None";

    }

    self.phoneNumber2.text = phone;


}
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you trying to put the same value into a second text field, a different value from the same address record, or information from a different address record?

Comment: Second UITextField is for a second phone number from the same address record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your second `UITextField` is for a second phone number, if it exists? You could then do:

```
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 1) {
   phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 1);
} else {
    phone = @"[None]";
}

self.phoneNumber2.text = phone;
```

Or you can use `CFBridgingRelease` instead of `__bridge_transfer`:

```
phone = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 1));
```

And, by the way, wouldn't you also want to use `ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex` to capture what type each phone number was (it doesn't help to know what a phone number is if you don't know what type of number it is). You could store these two phone number labels in two additional UITextFields (presumably next to their respective phone numbers).

---

**Update:**

I originally thought that you were looking for two phone numbers from the same contact. I'm now inferring from your user interface, where you have a "+" button next to each of the two phone number text fields that you want to tap on the button, and pull up the phone number for that text field. And then you'd then tap on the "+" button next to the other text field, and then pull up the phone number for a different contact and put it in that text field.

So, if this is the case, you might add an ivar to your class, such as:

```
int _phoneNumberIndex;
```

And then the first "+" button would have an `IBAction` like:

```
- (IBAction)showPicker1:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    _phoneNumberIndex = 1;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Whereas the second "+" button would have an `IBAction` like:

```
- (IBAction)showPicker2:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    _phoneNumberIndex = 2;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Then your `displayPerson` would be something like:

```
- (void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    // first name

    NSString* name = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));

    self.firstName.text = name;

    // phone numbers

    NSString* phone;

    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    // first phone number

    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0)
        phone = CFBridingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0));
    else
        phone = @"[None]";

    if (_phoneNumberIndex == 1)
        self.phoneNumber.text = phone;
    else if (_phoneNumberIndex == 2)
        self.phoneNumber2.text = phone;
    else
        NSLog(@"Unrecognized _phoneNumberIndex");

    CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
}
```

By the way, while I think this does what you're looking for, it's not clear what you should be doing with the first name field (because you're picking two contacts, which first name do you want to use, or will you store the two first names in two fields, just like you do with phone numbers?). So, you'll have to look at that.

Clearly, if you didn't want two `IBAction` methods for the two "+" buttons, you could probably do a single one that looked at `sender` or it's tag, but that's not material to your question. Bottom line, use an ivar to designate which phone number you want to update.

Comment: Second UITextField is for a second phone number from the same address record. I added your code, but it conflict with first UITextField and gives me an "None" to textfield. I edited the question.

Comment: @PavelKaljunen By the way, I just noticed that you're not releasing the `ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers` when you're done with it. Leak! Don't forget `CFRelease(phoneNumbers);` when you're done retrieving the numbers.

Comment: @PavelKaljunen I just tested the code myself and both phone numbers are coming back fine (when there are two different phone numbers for the contact). What do you mean when you say "conflict[s] with the first UITextField"? What precisely is happening? Given the code above works for me, I wonder if there's some problem with how you've linked the text fields to their IBOutlets in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes you're right, this code works! Can you help me some more with same function. I need now to retrieve phone number from other address record to second textfield. Hope you understand what I mean. Thank you!

Comment: @PavelKaljunen I'm afraid I'm note entirely sure what you mean. When you say "other address record", do you mean a different contact (e.g. a different ABRecordRef)? If so, how are you identifying that contact? Kicking off another ABPeoplePickerNavigationController? If that's the case, then you'd probably want to set some ivar before opening the picker to designate whether you're picking for phone number 1 or phone number 2, and then in your displayPerson method you'd want to check that ivar so you'd know which phone number to update. But if you're trying to do something else, let me know.

Comment: @PavelKaljunen I've updated my answer above assuming that this was indeed the case, that you wanted to pick two different contacts and see their respective phone numbers in the appropriate text field.

Comment: I am very grateful for your help! All works perfect and that what I just needed. Sorry for bad formulation of the problem. Thx!